# Form confirmation breaking my workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I have a form designed in Infopath 2010 (with Sharepoint on Office 365). When submitted, it puts the info into a list and kicks off a workflow that sends emails to the GMs. We decided to add a second view to the form, with a confirmation message. So that once the form is submitted, the user sees a little message with a thanks and a confirmation.

Having the confirmation utterly destroys the workflow, though. The submitted item shows up in the list, and its workflow status is "in progress," but none of the emails get sent. I submitted several forms, and got nothing. When I removed the confirmation and submitted another form, the workflow ran beautifully.

Any thoughts why or how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of adding a second view can't you redirect the user to a page in SharePoint which has the mentioned message? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41291/redirect-a-user-after-submitting-an-infopath-form

Comment: Yeah, eventually I allowed the form to have a pop-up window that gave a confirmation. It was just such a strange thing to break a workflow. The mysteries of Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a second view can't you redirect the user to a page in SharePoint which has the mentioned message

[Redirect a user after submitting an InfoPath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41291/redirect-a-user-after-submitting-an-infopath-form)